# Extension Malfunctioning on Windows

Tags: javascript, typescript, windows, vscode-extensions

I programmed an extension (on Visual Studio Code) for Visual Studio code on my Mac, and it was working perfectly fine. However, when I tried running the same extension on Windows 11, it wasn't working as expected to. Although my extension executed, it wasn't giving the correct output for any input.

I kept seeing this error in the terminal:
stack trace: Error: This platform (arm64-win32) is not supported

Side note: The extension is running for projects made from the C programming language.

I tried looking for online sources for help, but nothing fixed this issue. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Your Mac has Apple silicon?

Comment: In a more technical way, what does your extension do? Is it calling some sort of native binary perhaps? Maybe a compiler or such? The error you are seeing in the console, can you see where it is thrown?

Comment: Is it pure js/ts that you bundled up?

Comment: My Mac has the M1 chip so yes it is a silicon @DaveNewton

Comment: In my extension I have a UI and when a button is clicked it sends a request to an API which then provides the response to the user as a notification. In terms of the error, I see that its thrown in the extensionHostProcess.js file and extension.js file (I haven't tinkered these files in any way). Error: rejected promise not handled within 1 second: Error: This platform (arm64-win32) is not suported.
extensionHostProcess.js:104
stack trace: Error: This platform (arm64-win32) is not suported.
 at c:\Users\...\.vscode\extensions\vadimcn.vscode-lldb-1.9.2\extension.js:1:28136 @Karl-JohanSjögren

Comment: yes its pure ts @LelandB

Comment: Seems like the extension is being built/bundled w/ Arm arch. I don't know how that's handled w/ VS Code but I'd start looking for how to differentiate architectures.